# Linux load very high, processes low

Tags: linux

Running a Linux server and this is not the first time this happens (and still nobody on any forum could explain it to me)

I'm monitoring my server with New Relic, so it opened an alert for >80% usage. I logged in and ran htop. Load average of 1.30, CPU way over 100%.. BUT.. no process is taking CPU%. Process that takes most would go up to 5% then back to 0 or 2.

What could be going on? :(

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a combination of things going on in your htop output / configuration that result in it appearing as though 'nothing' is responsible for the the 100% CPU utilization reported in the display bar. Is this a single core machine (VM)?

**kernel processes:**

By default htop does not display kernel processes in the thread list (top does). You can toggle the display of kernel processes by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. Since the `Tasks:` section lists no kernel threads (kthr), it's clear they are currently hidden.

**sort by CPU utilization:**

You do not have the process list currently sorted by CPU utilization. Hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> key and use the arrow keys to select PERCENT_CPU. This will allow you to see the processes that are almost certainly currently hidden from view (off the bottom of the list) that are using a non zero percentage of the CPU.

**CPU utilization indicator bar:**

One clue that the kernel processes are not being displayed is the cpu bar, which shows that (roughly) 40% of the CPU is being used by the kernel, which we can tell by the color of the various portions constituting the CPU 'visual' representation htop provides. The colors are defined as:

> [System wide cpu usage:](http://www.deonsworld.co.za/2012/12/20/understanding-and-using-htop-monitor-system-resources/)   
>  Blue: low priority processes (nice > 0)   
>  
>   Green: normal (user) processes.   
>    Red: kernel processes.  
>   Yellow: IRQ time. 
>    Magenta: Soft IRQ time.    
>   Grey: IO Wait time.

**still see a discrepancy?**

A method to get time averaged rather than effectively instantaneous CPU utilization numbers is discussed in the answer to a somewhat similar question on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/387268/linux-cpu-usage-and-process-execution-history). Collecting that data and comparing against the CPU utilization of 100% will let you get a much clearer picture of what is 'pegging' your CPU. Another answer to the same question references a tool called atop which is also very useful for analyzing CPU utilization over time as well as instantaneous snapshot type views like those that htop primarily provides.

**single core**
Since it appears that your server is operating with only a single core, the impact of kernel mode context changes can be more significant - when code is running in kernel context (interrupts, some IO syncing operations, etc.) there is no where for the OS scheduler to place user processes to run, a capability we are accustomed to with today's nearly universal use of [SMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) machines.